# How to debug trigger.io android 4.4 apps?

Tags: trigger.io, android-4.4-kitkat

Android 4.4 uses chromium, I'm trying to use chrome dev tools to debug my app. However, I cannot find my app in the ADB console (yet the device is detected, and  I can see chrome tabs on my device). Any idea how to enable debugging for my app?

Here [chrome-remote-debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews) it says that in order to configure web view for debugging one needs to call setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled - does trigger.io do that?

Comment: Have you set **remote_debugging=true** for the Core Trigger.io module? This [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24280679/514118) has more information.