# Cannot get remote WebView debugging to run on Android 4.4 Trigger.io app

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, remote-debugging, trigger.io

I'm trying to enable [remote debugging for WebViews](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews) on a [Trigger.io](https://trigger.io/) app running on Nexus 7 (Android 4.4.3). I've created a [native module](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html) to set the Webview property with the following method:

```
public static void enableWebViewDebugging(final ForgeTask task) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
    task.success();
}
```

I call it from JS with `forge.internal.call('utils.enableWebViewDebugging', {}, null, null);` a few seconds after the app started.

When looging at the `chrome://inspect/#devices` tab, I only see Chrome browser tabs, but no native WebView/app whatsoever.

Is there anything wrong with the way I set the property? I could imagine, that the WebView property must be set during a specific startup/oncreate method, however is that even possible with Trigger.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger.io natively supports remote debugging for Android > 4.4 so you shouldn't need to create your own custom module.

To enable it you can go to your app config in Trigger Toolkit and enable the checkbox at: Core => Android => Remote Debugging

Alternatively, edit your src/config.json file directly and add the 'remote_debugging' key to the core.android section:

```
"core": {
                "android": {
                        "remote_debugging": true,
                }
},
```

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that, thanks for the info! Btw: the issue with my native module was that the WebView property needs to be toggled on the UI thread. So wrapping my code in `ForgeApp.getActivity().runOnUiThread` made it work. However, using the Trigger.io config is obviously the best way.